# Is it possible to perform vectorized calculations with arrays of pointers?

Tags: arrays, pointers, fortran, vectorization

I have a recurring calculation in my code that I would like to vectorize to decrease run time. The calculation is the mean squared error (MSE) between two vectors representing the head and tail values of a separation lag vector in space. That is, some number of data pairs separated by vector **h**.

The MSE is a component of an objective function which is minimized iteratively. The problem I am running into is the values at the head and tail locations change on each iteration (new candidate vector) and I am currently iterating over each pair to update the values in `head` and `tail`. It's not an issue in a toy example, but in practice there may be tens of thousands of iterations over tens of thousands of pairs. This operation currently represents 75% of the total program run time so the savings from cutting out a loop over all pairs may be substantial.

What I thought I could do is define `head` and `tail` as arrays of pointers where each element points to the corresponding value of that index in `values`. The `head` and `tail` indices are constant and only need to be calculated once, however `values` is updated on each iteration. I thought this would remove the need to update the `head` and `tail` values in a loop and I could simply do `mse = sum((head - tail)**2)/npair` though obviously I cannot perform arithmetic on `type(dataptr)`. A small example is below:

```
program main

   implicit none

   type :: dataptr
      real(8), pointer :: ptr
   end type dataptr

   integer, parameter :: niter = 10, ndata = 5, npair = 15
   integer :: i, j, k
   real(8), target :: values(ndata)
   real(8) :: mse
   integer :: ihead(npair), itail(npair)
   type(dataptr) :: head(npair), tail(npair)

   ! get the indices of all data pairs
   k = 1
   do i = 1, ndata
      do j = i, ndata
         ihead(k) = i
         itail(k) = j
         k = k + 1
      end do
   end do

   ! head and tail point to corresponding values in `values`
   do i = 1, npair
      head(i)%ptr => values(ihead(i))
      tail(i)%ptr => values(itail(i))
   end do

   ! main loop
   do i = 1, niter

      ! arbitrarily update values on each iteration for example
      call random_number(values)

      ! I would like to vectorize the MSE between head and tail
      !   mse = 0.d0
      !   mse = sum((head - tail)**2)/npair ! this doesn't work as head and tail are type(dataptr)

      ! rather than iterating over all pairs
      mse = 0.d0
      do j = 1, npair
         mse = mse + (values(ihead(j)) - values(itail(j)))**2 ! this does work, but slower
      end do
      mse = mse/npair
      
   end do

end program main
```

I am relatively new to Fortran so I am wondering:

1. Is it possible to vectorize this calculation with arrays of pointers?
2. Is this even a reasonable approach? I open to completely refactoring my work if it makes sense.

Example was compiled with `GNU Fortran (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0`

Comment: What do you mean by "array of pointers"? "arrays of pointers where each element points to the corresponding value of that index" isn't how Fortran works.

Comment: What you are trying to do is unclear to me, and I can see several issues in your code. 1) in your first double loop, `k` will raise to `ndata**2 = 25`, while `ihead` and `itail` are dimensionned to `npair = 15` 2) in you last loop on `j` you are doing `npair` times the exact same operation (I guess the arrays should be indexed with `j` rather than `i`)

Comment: Apart from that, there's no chance you can vectorize this calculation by using pointers: the pattern access to the data in memory won't change, despite the notation that could give the illusion it will.

Comment: With the pointer approach you would write `mse = sum((head(:)%ptr - tail(:)%ptr)**2)/npair`. But it will be even slower than your "normal" approach.

Comment: @francescalus is it not possible to have an array of pointers where, say, the first two elements point to one element in another array, the second two point to another element etc. ? I guess I'm looking for non-contiguous access to `values`.

Comment: @PierU (1) `k` is only raised to 15 as the inner loop is `do j = i, npair`; (2) the final loop should be indexed by `j`.  Using `mse = sum((head(:)%ptr - tail(:)%ptr)**2)/npair` gives me the error `Component to the right of a part reference with nonzero rank must not have the POINTER attribute at (1)`. Suppose I will live with my current implementation.

Comment: OK, I misread the double loop... For the notation `head(:)%ptr` I didn't know (or forgot) that it could not work with a pointer component... That said you could write you current solution without a loop, using array indexing: `mse = sum((values(ihead(:)) - values(itail(:)))**2)`. BUT still, it won't vectorize... Again, it's not because there is an array notation that vectorization can occur.

Comment: "Array of pointers" would naively be taken as C-like languages have it: each element of the array being a pointer. What you have in the code is not that: each element of the array has a _component_ which is a pointer. Very different things.

Comment: Noncontiguous and vectorization are not things that fit together.

Comment: @PierU I think this is just a clash of terminology. Most people here assume that vectorization=SIMD=vector CPU instructions. I think the OP means the vector notation=vectorization, based on how this term is used in Python and NumPy. It might be useful to explain or point to an explanation od the difference between these two. This kind of terminological confusion hapoened here several times before. Some askers also expect some speedup from the "vector" array notation based on their Python experiences not knowing that Fortran works differently.

Comment: @b.e.harding Cpuld you please confirm what exactly you mean by [tag:vectorization]? Several different concepts can and had been be called by that name. Confusion is very common.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I was referring to vectorization as array statements instead of loops as in `c(:) = a(:) + b(:)`, though now I see that is not the case in fortran.

Comment: Thanks, the tag description agrees with this kind of meaning. But the earlier comments about the restrictions with pointer and allocatable components do apply.

Comment: OK, so I misunderstood the question... Still you can use array notation to replace your last loop on j: `mse = sum((values(ihead(:)) - values(itail(:)))**2)`

Comment: Note however, as mentionned by @VladimirFГероямслава, that array notation generally doesn't give speed-up in Fortran. Not because Fortran is bad at that, but because classical loops are already perfectly optimized by usual compilers (as opposed to what happens with an interpreted language like Python or Matlab)